# redirect on ajax create

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Is it possible to redirect to different location in controller during ajax processing? I mean that I send an AJAX request but during its processing in controller I find out that I want to cancel the ajax request and redirect to completely different location. I'm using this in my customer form. It works like this: someone clicks create button on my form, it checks attributes of form via ajax, if they are wrong it returns errors otherwise it redirects to new customer.
Any ideas?

Comment: that's more a javascript question than ruby on rails

Comment: It also sounds more like a validation which, assuming you don't want a page refresh in the middle, like RageZ said, it probably better solved via JavaScript. So, something like client side validation via jQuery, for example. (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: YOu can use 'window.location = location;' in js.erb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found something much more better so here's the code that you need to add to application_controller:

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
  if request.xhr?
    render(:update) { |page| page.redirect_to(options) }
  else
    super(options, response_status)
  end 
end
```

and then in action use standard `redirect_to`

Answer (score 0):

You cant redirect from the controller but after completion of attribute checking you return "success" on successful checking.You can check in jquery whether the value is success or not.Refer the following example for better understanding.

```
$.post(
    "http://localhost/photo_tool/index.php/photo_tool/login",
    {
       username:$('#username').val(),
       password:$('#password').val()
    },
    function(result){
    if(result=='success')
    {   
      window.location.href = 'Your URL here';
      //You can also use window.location.replace("Your URL here");
    }
    else
    {
     $('#error').html(result);
    }
  });
```

In above example controller returns 'success' on successful login.